# Python and PYAML - yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am on ubunty 64 with python 2.7 and using PyYAML-3.10

Below is my yaml file:

```
host:localhost
username:root
password:test
database:test
operations_database:operations
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

When I run the below code I get the below error.   But if I remove the lines above the treeroot the code works:

```
from yaml import load, dump
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper
f=open('amazon.yaml')  
data = load(f, Loader=Loader) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Amazon-Products-Crawler-1/config_files/test_yaml.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = load(f, Loader=Loader) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 58, in compose_document
    self.get_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 118, in get_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 193, in parse_document_end
    token = self.peek_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 128, in peek_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 220, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_value()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 580, in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "amazon.yaml", line 6, column 9
```

Comment: I made it work reindenting the line, and if needed the whole file

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try putting spaces after the colons.

Comment: A simple way to improve your answer would be to show the correctly formatted YAML file.

Comment: I don't think it's just a matter of collon. I have the issue here while having after the collon...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914422/parse-aws-cloudformation-template-with-yaml-library

Comment: The error may also appear when you have wrong indentation in line. That was my case.

Answer (score 30):

**For anyone who comes here and finds that even if they have spaces after the colon, they still get this error**

You can also get this error if you copy the yaml text from some formatted source (for me it was a Slack message).  This will invisibly swap in non-ASCII characters that the standard YAML reader can't read, but which look the same.

Solution is to only copy from raw, ASCII source.

Comment: This worked for me since I was copying from a website directly. Once I deleted the file and wrote the whole yaml file myself, it worked. Such intricacies. Thanks

Comment: Dear God... this was the problem.

Comment: I literally hate YAML :)

Comment: Your answer deserves to come first!

Comment: thank you so much! you've saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 9):

If someone comes here and has formatting and spaces right but the error persists.

Check if there is colon after the version! (me facepalming duh)

Error:

```
version '3.7'

services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
```

Fixed:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
```

Answer (score 6):

yaml files do not accept values immediately after the colon mark in the file content. Enter the value after a space, save the file and run again, the error will be gone. I had encountered the similar error during my automation using BDD, and got this fixed after a lot of debugging.

Comment: I don't think it's just a matter of collon. I have the issue here while having after the collon...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914422/parse-aws-cloudformation-template-with-yaml-library

Answer (score 1):

I also get the same error when a section isnt indented correctly. In my case the lower line was over-indented.

Wrong:

```
tags:
  - name: my_tag
parameters:
  - in: path
        name: id
```

corrected:

```
tags:
  - name: my_tag
parameters:
  - in: path
    name: id
```

Sadly, this is recognized as a "mapping values" error as well.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions above, I still got the same error. What worked for me was to create a `.yml` file directly from vscode and copy the content to that file and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird behavior regarding this. I have a yml file that I can read without any problem in my local machine. When I moved it to the server (Windows 2019) I started getting this error. Tried all thing suggested here but nothing worked. So I removed the first line which was just a comment and it started working.

Comment: Are you sure this answer the reported issue? Did you also have a "*yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here*" error?

Comment: yes.. exactly the same message.